# Class-level memoization vs Constants. What is the difference? Which one to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a rails app, where I have a class with a large constant. The reviewer asked me use a self method instead, stating that having a large constant will increase the application startup time. But I don't see the difference or the advantage.

Can you please help me understand the difference?

```
class Test
  X = [1, 2, 3]
  def self.x
    @_x ||= [1, 2, 3]
  end
end

Test::X

Test.x
```

Comment: The class method defers creation of the array until it is called for the first time wheres the constant variant creates the array the moment you load the class file. However, if your array is so large that it affects startup time (did you verify?), you might consider a different approach. Can you share some insights?

Answer (score 2):

When Ruby encounters a `class` keyword it evaluates the class body right away (same for `module`). You might want to try this in [IRB](https://github.com/ruby/irb):

```
class Foo
  puts 'I got evaluated'
end
# I got evaluated
```

That's why your constant assignment is evaluated the moment you load the class file.

Methods on the other hand have to be called explicitly:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'I got evaluated'
  end
end

Foo.bar
# I got evaluated
```

Conditionally assigning your array to an instance variable in a method defers the creation until you actually need (i.e. call) it.

Your example with debug output added:

```
class Test
  X = (puts 'X assigned' ; [1, 2, 3])
  def self.x
    @_x ||= (puts '@_x assigned' ; [1, 2, 3])
  end
end
# X assigned    <-- constant from class body

Test::X
#=> [1, 2, 3]

Test.x
# @_x assigned  <-- instance variable from method
#=> [1, 2, 3]

Test.x
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```